Is it still possible to compile modern x264 with the nal long start code used prior to release r1510?
I'm currently nerding out on old technology with HD-DVDs. The only freely available muxer is hddvdmux, I'm using MultiAVCHD for this.
Beginning with r1510, x264 switched to short start packets for NAL HRD (from what I understand). This makes the stream incompatible with hddvdmux.
deank on doom9 patched hddvdmux to accept short start codes, but in doing so, the video file plays too quickly and the audio goes out of sync.
The results I'm getting from the 2009 release of x264 leave much to be desired in comparison to modern releases, and I'd like to get those benefits while still maintaining compatibility with the original hddvdmux.
Is it possible? If so... Any chance someone could compile a Windows binary for me with that change? (I think it needs to be 32 bit, but not sure)
I've tried multiple options with MultiAVCHD 4.1, fell back to 4.0 but am seeing weird rainbowing effects in the color from the extremely old version if x264. I admit I haven't dived in to programming, but seemed like a single change might be a reasonable request from someone already knowledgeable.
